# In Python, what is the difference between `async for x in async_iterator` and `for x in await async_iterator`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

The subject contains the whole idea. I came accross code sample where it shows something like:

```py
async for item in getItems():
    await item.process()
```

And others where the code is:

```py
for item in await getItems():
    await item.process()
```

Is there a notable difference in these two approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

While both of them *could theoretically* work with the same object (without causing an error), they most likely **do not**. In general those two notations are **not equivalent at all**, but invoke entirely different protocols and are applied to very distinct use cases.

---

### Different protocols

##### Iterable

To understand the difference, you first need to understand the concept of an [**iterable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Abstractly speaking, an object is **iterable**, if it implements the [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method or (less common for iteration) a sequence-like `__getitem__` method.

Practically speaking, an object is **iterable**, if you can use it in a `for`-loop, so `for _ in iterable`. A `for`-loop implicitly invokes the `__iter__` method of the iterable and expects it to return an [**iterator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), which implements the [`__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method. That method is called at the start of each iteration in the `for`-loop and its return value is what is assigned to the loop variable.

##### Asynchronous iterable

The `async`-world introduced a variation of that, namely the [**asynchronous iterable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterable).

An object is **asynchronously iterable**, if it implements the [`__aiter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__aiter__) method.

Again, practically speaking, an object is **asynchronously iterable**, if it can be used in an `async for`-loop, so `async for _ in async_iterable`. An `async for`-loop calls the `__aiter__` method of the asynchronous iterable and expects it to return an [**asynchronous iterator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterator), which implements the [`__anext__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__anext__) coroutine method. That method is awaited at the start of each iteration of the `async for`-loop.

##### Awaitable

Typically speaking, an asynchronous iterable is **not [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable)**, i.e. it is not a coroutine and it does not implement an [`__await__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#awaitable-objects) method and vice versa. Although they are not necessarily mutually exclusive. You could design an object that is both awaitable by itself and also (asynchronously) iterable, though that seems like a very strange design.

##### (Asynchronous) Iterator

Just to be very clear in the terminology used, the itera**tor** is a *subtype* of the itera**ble**. Meaning an iterator also implements the iterable protocol by providing an `__iter__` method, but it also provides the `__next__` method. Analogously, the **asynchronous iterator** is a subtype of the asynchronous iterable because it implements the `__aiter__` method, but also provides the `__anext__` coroutine method.

You do not *need* the object to be an iterator for it to be used in a `for`-loop, you need it to *return* an iterator. The fact that you can use an (asynchronous) iterator in a (`async`) `for`-loop is because it is also an (asynchronous) iterable. It is just rare for something to be an iterable but *not* an iterator. In most cases the object will be both (i.e. the latter).

---

### Inferences from your example

##### `async for _ in get_items()`

That code implies that whatever is *returned* by the `get_items` function is an asynchronous iterable.

Note that `get_items` is just a normal non-`async` function, but the object it returns implements the asynchronous iterable protocol. That means we could write the following instead:

```py
async_iterable = get_items()
async for item in async_iterable:
    ...
```

##### `for _ in await get_items()`

Whereas this snippet implies that `get_items` *is* in fact a [coroutine function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine-function) (i.e. a callable returning an awaitable) and the return value of that coroutine is a *normal* iterable.

Note that we know for certain that the object returned by the `get_items` coroutine is a *normal* iterable because otherwise the regular `for`-loop would not work with it. The equivalent code would be:

```py
iterable = await get_items()
for item in iterable:
    ...
```

##### Implications

Another implication of those code snippets is that in the first one **the function** (returning the asynchronous iterator) **is non-asynchronous**, i.e. calling it will not yield control to the event loop, whereas each **iteration** of the `async for`-loop **is asynchronous** (and thus will allow context switches).

Conversely, in the second one the function returning the normal iterator is an **asynchronous** call, but all of the iterations (the calls to `__next__`) are **non-asynchronous**.

##### Key difference

The practical takeaway should be that those two snippets you showed are *never* equivalent. The main reason is that `get_items` either is or is not a coroutine function. If it is *not*, you cannot do `await get_items()`. But whether or not you can do `async for` or `for` depends on whatever is returned by `get_items`.

---

### Possible combinations

For the sake of completion, it should be noted that combinations of the aforementioned protocols are entirely feasible, although not all too common. Consider the following example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    x = 0

    def __iter__(self) -> Foo:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> int:
        if self.x >= 2:
            raise StopIteration
        self.x += 1
        return self.x

    def __aiter__(self) -> Foo:
        return self

    async def __anext__(self) -> int:
        if self.x >= 3:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.x += 1
        return self.x * 10


async def main() -> None:
    for i in Foo():
        print(i)
    async for i in Foo():
        print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from asyncio import run
    run(main())
```

In this example, `Foo` implements four distinct protocols:

- iterable (`def __iter__`)
- iterator (iterable + `def __next__`)
- asynchronous iterable (`def __aiter__`)
- asynchronous iterator (asynchronous iterable + `async def __anext__`)

Running the `main` coroutine gives the following output:

```
1
2
10
20
30
```

This shows that objects can absolutely be all those things at the same time. Since `Foo` is both a synchronous and an asynchronous iterable, we could write two functions -- one coroutine, one regular -- that each returns an instance of `Foo` and then replicate your example a bit:

```py
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable, Iterable


def get_items_sync() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    return Foo()


async def get_items_async() -> Iterable[int]:
    return Foo()


async def main() -> None:
    async for i in get_items_sync():
        print(i)
    for i in await get_items_async():
        print(i)
    async for i in await get_items_async():
        print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from asyncio import run
    run(main())
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
1
2
10
20
30
```

This illustrates very clearly that the **only** thing determining which of our `Foo` methods is called (`__next__` or `__anext__`) is whether we use a `for`-loop or an `async for`-loop.

The `for`-loop will **always** call the `__next__` method at least once and continue calling it for each iteration, until it intercepts a `StopIteration` exception.

The `async for`-loop will **always** await the `__anext__` coroutine at least once and continue calling and awaiting it for each subsequent iteration, until it intercepts a `StopAsyncIteration` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Those are completely different.

This `for item in await getItems()` won't work (will throw an error) if `getItems()` is an asynchronous iterator or asynchronous generator, it may be used only if `getItems` is a coroutine which, in your case, is expected to return a sequence object (simple iterable).

`async for` is a conventional (and pythonic) way for asynchronous iterations over *async* iterator/generator.