# asyncio to download data in batches and return a list of lists

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to download data in batches asynchronously.

The data for each `name` is downloaded in batches, and I'd like `asyncio.gather(*coroutines)` to return a list of lists (a list of batches for each name). So far I have this code, but it raises an exception:

```py
import asyncio
import datetime


async def run(names):
    """Start one coroutine for each name."""
    coroutines = [_fetch_data(name) for name in names]
    return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)  # This fails!


async def _fetch_data(name):
    """Fetch data for a single symbol in batches."""
    start_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1).timestamp()
    end_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 2).timestamp()

    i = 1
    while start_timestamp < end_timestamp:
        batch = f"Batch {i} for {name}"
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Some async API call, for example
        # If I remove the yield, it works. But I want to use the results!
        yield batch
        start_timestamp += 3600
        i += 1


async def main():
    names = ["Jack", "Jill", "Bob"]
    return await run(names)


output = asyncio.run(main())
print(output)
# I'd expect something like 
# [["Batch 1 for Jack", "Batch 2 for Jack", ...], ["Batch 1 for Jill", "Batch 2 for Jill", ...], ...]
```

Unfortunately, this code returns an exception for `asyncio.gather(*coroutines)`:

> TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Isn't `_fetch_data` a coroutine? What is this error trying to tell me? And how can I get past it?

I'm trying to learn more about asyncio in Python and I'm quite sure I'm missing some basics here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `_fetch_data` is not a coroutine function. By using a `yield` statement inside it you turned it into an [asynchronous generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator), which is not awaitable by default. See [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75372032) about the distinction.

If you *actually* want it to be a generator and you want multiple `async` generators to be consumed concurrently, you'll need to modify your code a bit and introduce a coroutine that asynchronously consumes the generator. This is typically done via an `async for`-loop.

Something like this will work:

```py
...

async def run(names):
    coroutines = [fetch(name) for name in names]
    return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)


async def fetch(name):
    return [batch async for batch in _fetch_data(name)]

...
```

I don't know your actual use case, so I don't know, if using a generator is actually prudent here. But alternatively you could of course sidestep the entire issue by just making `_fetch_data` an actual coroutine function that returns a list, rather than an asynchronous generator *yielding* list items:

```py
import asyncio
import datetime


async def run(names):
    return await asyncio.gather(*(_fetch_data(name) for name in names))


async def _fetch_data(name):
    start_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1).timestamp()
    end_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 2).timestamp()
    results = []
    i = 1
    while start_timestamp < end_timestamp:
        batch = f"Batch {i} for {name}"
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Some async API call, for example
        results.append(batch)
        start_timestamp += 3600
        i += 1
    return results


async def main():
    names = ["Jack", "Jill", "Bob"]
    return await run(names)


output = asyncio.run(main())
print(output)
```

Both of these work, produce the output you expect, and are (at least with your simplified example) essentially equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, this seems exactly what I was looking for. As far as I understand, this `_fetch_data()` will give back control to the async loop every time it waits for a new batch. Is this correct?

Comment: If you mean the second code snippet, as usual it will allow a context switch whenever it hits an `await` expression, so at the `asyncio.sleep` call. In your original code, technically `yield` will also allow a context switch, though that seems rather useless in that example. But you can just try and run it. By timing the execution you should see the concurrency in action.